# How to read Perl DB_Files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, berkeley-db

I'm migrating a Perl script to Ruby. The Perl script uses DB_File in [DB_HASH](http://perldoc.perl.org/DB_File.html#DB_HASH) mode.
How do I read all the keys and values from such a file in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally realized that DB_HASH is a [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) file format.

I didn't have libdb for Ruby on my Ubuntu box but that was fixed with a simple apt-get

> apt-get install libdb4.2-ruby1.8

Then in Ruby

```
require 'bdb'
db=BDB::Hash.open("test.db")
keyvalues=db.to_hash
```